# How to use files from zip file without extracting in Android

Tags: android, zip

I need to read JSON file and install some apk file stored in zip encrypted file without extracting to storage. 
Is there are any way how to do it? 
Maybe extract into some virtual storage, or possible way use files without extracting.

Comment: What do you mean with storage? You could extract it to your internal application file folder `getFilesDir()` or into cache `getCacheDir()`, so it's not public readable.

Comment: @Mr.Fish I mean, read files without extracting or extract into virtual space. I think getCacheDir() could be the solution. I will check it. Thank you.

Comment: @Mr.Fish Unfortunately, the cache is not suitable. I have to extract into virtual file system. Is it possible?